# How to create 1000 files all the same but change some specific parameter?

Tags: fortran

I need to make around 1000 inputs files each is almost similar but change some parameters, how to create 1000 files all the same but change some specific parameter?

Is there a way to copy the file data and make it as output after I change a variable value?

```
========================================================================
=arp
ce16x16
5
3
0.2222222
0.2222222
0.2222222
60
60
60
1
1
1
0.71
ft33f001
end
#origens
0$$ a4 33 all 71 e t
ce16x16
3$$ 33 a3 1 27 a16 2 a33 18 e t
35$$ 0 t 
56$$ 10 10 a6 3 a10 0 a13 4 a15 3 a18 1 e
95$$ 0 t
cycle 1 -fo3
1 MTU
58** 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 
60 ** 0.02222222 0.04444444 0.06666667 0.08888889 0.1111111 0.1333333
 0.1555556 0.1777778 0.2 0.2222222
66$$ a1 2 a5 2 a9 2 e
73$$ 922340 922350 922360 922380
74** 445 50000 230 949325
75$$ 2 2 2 2 
t
====================================================================
```

This a part of the file, I would like to make 1000 files similar to this, but only change the values of 60 each time.

The value of 60 is equal some value entered by the user divider by (0.2222222).

Comment: Welcome, pkease take the [tour] and read [ask]. Even though you are a beginner,,this is a coding site, not a programming service. We are here to answer questions about programming, not write code for you. You should open a textbook or tutorial and learn the basics and try to write some code yourself and then ask about your problems with it. Please also do care about the way you write your questions. Code should be formatted as code, sentences should start with a capiral letter - see the edits.

Comment: Is there a reason to do that with Fortran? I'd much rather use Python for this. Also, this is not a program writing service.

Comment: There are much better tools for this than writing a program to do this task. Have a look at `sed`, `awk`, `perl` or `python`. You can probably just do it in a single line.

Comment: thank you all, i am asked to do in Fortran. but i still will be grateful if you supply me with a code with matlab to do to